# Async Task Response delay

Tags: android, wcf, android-asynctask, response

I am attempting to consume a WCF service with android. I implement my task as follows.

```
class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    String msg = "";

    public void setMsg(String msg)
    {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    public String getMsg()
    {
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... url) {
        String line="";
        Hashing hashing = new Hashing();

        try 
        {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                EditText edit_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPasswordRegister);
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.0.0.14/server/UserManagement.svc/ping");
                httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    setMsg(line);

                }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return line;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        TextView view = (...)findViewById(...);
        view.setText(getMsg());



    }

}
```

I call `new HttpReqestTask().execute()` in my main `onCreate` method. As seen in the post execute the result is written to a Text View.

When I now attempt to write the content in the text view to a text edit I get a empty text edit. The resend for this is that the task is in a RUNNING state.

```
HttpReqestTask task = new HttpReqestTask();
task.execute();
TextView view = (...)findViewById(...);
TextView result = (...)findViewById(...);
result.setText(view.getText().toString());
```

How can I get a part of code to run after the task is FINISHED? I attempted to use a for loop that checks if the state is FINISHED of the task and only write to the Text View when it is finished but that did not work.

Comment: Can you not just put it in onPostExecute?

Comment: @hoomi No I want to use the result outside of the task.

Comment: To be honest I do not understand what you want. Is it possible to showbthe out sidw code? Is HttpRequestTask an inner class?